How to Change Multiple Values in a json file
I want to change the values in a json file. The json file contents are commented out. I want to change the values individually with having to write to the file separately for each value.
import json

"""
{
    "keys": {
        "developer": {},
        "personal": {
            "api_key": "1234567890",
            "client_id": "9876543210",
            "client_secret": "ncjegcbcncwkwdcowdch"
        }
    }
}
"""

json_file = "/home/api_keys.json"

with open(json_file) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

with open(json_file, "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)

    data["keys"]["personal"]["api_key"] = "9999"

with open(json_file, "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)   

    data["keys"]["personal"]["client_id"] = "000000000000"

with open(json_file, "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)

    data["keys"]["personal"]["client_secret"] = "hyfgdjocoduxbxlwowichcnckw"

with open(json_file) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

    api_key = data["keys"]["personal"]["api_key"]
    client_id = data["keys"]["personal"]["client_id"]
    client_secret = data["keys"]["personal"]["client_secret"]


skip all the extra json.dump calls.  Just load, change all the data and call dump at the end.

Sorry, what are you asking? This code doesn't quite do what you want, so I guess you want help with changing it, but what do you need help with exactly? For tips, check out How to ask a good question.

Did you mean to say "without having to write to the file separately for each value"? In that case, why did you think you had to do multiple writes in the first place?

Beside the point, but json_file and jsonFile are essentially the same name but in different conventions, so it'd be good to rename them to avoid confusion. If I were you, I'd rename json_file to something like json_filename or json_path, then rename jsonFile to json_file to follow the convention you're using elsewhere in the script, like api_key, and standard Python convention.

Short answer: read once, update json, and then write once. No need to write multiple times.
Also, you can change the orders of your variables that you want to set: api_key, client_id, and client_secret. (thanks @wjandrea)
import json

"""
{
    "keys": {
        "developer": {},
        "personal": {
            "api_key": "1234567890",
            "client_id": "9876543210",
            "client_secret": "ncjegcbcncwkwdcowdch"
        }
    }
}
"""

json_file = "/home/api_keys.json"

api_key = "9999"
client_id = "000000000000"
client_secret = "hyfgdjocoduxbxlwowichcnckw"

with open(json_file) as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

data["keys"]["personal"]["api_key"] = api_key
data["keys"]["personal"]["client_id"] = client_id
data["keys"]["personal"]["client_secret"] = client_secret

with open(json_file, "w") as jsonFile:
    json.dump(data, jsonFile)


What's the point of api_key = data["keys"]["personal"]["api_key"] if it's unused and you just set the value yourself?
